# My code runs on local with warning, but not running on server

Tags: playorm

I Have a web app that needs to use PlayORM for  doing some work like insert/queries.
My code runs without any problem on local, but the following *warning* message appears:

> com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass
>   processIdFieldWorksWARN: We avoided double scanning a class=class
>   com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.data.MetaClassSingle Everything will still
>   work fine, but please send us the stack trace so we can see why this
>   is happening java.lang.RuntimeException: null at
>   com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.processIdFieldWorks(ScannerForClass.java:234)
>   [playorm-1.4.3.jar:1.4.3 December 13 2012]

But when I try to execute that code on a JSF page, the code does not work. Following is the error message:

> INFO  c.a.o.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass - scanning class=class
>   com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.meta.DboColumnMeta
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure scanning class(see chained
>   exception)=class com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.meta.DboColumnMeta

Do someone know what can I do to solve this problem?

UPDATE:

- first stack trace - works fine locally (running outsite web)

> 2013-02-13 19:20:18,173 com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass
>   processIdFieldWorksWARN: We avoided double scanning a class=class
>   com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.data.MetaClassSingle Everything will still
>   work fine, but please send us the stack trace so we can see why this
>   is happening java.lang.RuntimeException: null at
>   com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.processIdFieldWorks(ScannerForClass.java:234)
>   [playorm-1.4.3.jar:1.4.3 December 13 2012] at
>   com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.inspectFieldImpl(ScannerForClass.java:206)
>   [playorm-1.4.3.jar:1.4.3 December 13 2012] at
>   com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.inspectField(ScannerForClass.java:193)
>   [playorm-1.4.3.jar:1.4.3 December 13 2012] at
>   com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.scanFields(ScannerForClass.java:188)
>   [playorm-1.4.3.jar:1.4.3 December 13 2012] at
>   com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.scanSingle(ScannerForClass.java:111)
>   [playorm-1.4.3.jar:1.4.3 December 13 2012] at
>   com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.scanMultipleClasses(ScannerForClass.java:104)
>   [playorm-1.4.3.jar:1.4.3 December 13 2012] at
>   com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.addClass(ScannerForClass.java:64)
>   [playorm-1.4.3.jar:1.4.3 December 13 2012] at
>   com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.scanClass(MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.java:42)
>   [playorm-1.4.3.jar:1.4.3 December 13 2012] at
>   com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.discovered(MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.java:34)
>   [playorm-1.4.3.jar:1.4.3 December 13 2012] at
>   com.impetus.annovention.Discoverer.discoverAndIntimateForClassAnnotations(Discoverer.java:197)
>   [playorm-1.4.3.jar:1.4.3 December 13 2012] at
>   com.impetus.annovention.Discoverer.discover(Discoverer.java:155)
>   [playorm-1.4.3.jar:1.4.3 December 13 2012] at
>   com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl.rescan(BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:82)
>   [playorm-1.4.3.jar:1.4.3 December 13 2012] at
>   com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl.setup(BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:133)
>   [playorm-1.4.3.jar:1.4.3 December 13 2012] at
>   com.alvazan.orm.impl.bindings.BootstrapImpl.createInstanceImpl(BootstrapImpl.java:64)
>   [playorm-1.4.3.jar:1.4.3 December 13 2012] at
>   com.alvazan.orm.impl.bindings.BootstrapImpl.createInstance(BootstrapImpl.java:35)
>   [playorm-1.4.3.jar:1.4.3 December 13 2012] at
>   com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:57)
>   [playorm-1.4.3.jar:1.4.3 December 13 2012] at
>   com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:52)
>   [playorm-1.4.3.jar:1.4.3 December 13 2012] at
>   com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:45)
>   [playorm-1.4.3.jar:1.4.3 December 13 2012] at
>   com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:24)
>   [playorm-1.4.3.jar:1.4.3 December 13 2012] at
>   com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.dao.PlayOrmConfiguration.init(PlayOrmConfiguration.java:45)
>   [classes/:na] at
>   com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.dao.PlayOrmConfiguration.getEntityManager(PlayOrmConfiguration.java:51)
>   [classes/:na] at
>   com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.dao.AbstractDao.getEm(AbstractDao.java:10)
>   [classes/:na] at
>   com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.dao.UserDao.findInputPhase(UserDao.java:201)
>   [classes/:na] at
>   com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.bean.InputPhaseStru.manageInputPhase(InputPhaseStru.java:105)
>   [classes/:na] at
>   com.s1mbi0se.dashboard.service.DashboardService.readSolrLogFile(DashboardService.java:44)
>   [classes/:na] at
>   com.s1mbi0se.dashboard.service.DashboardService.main(DashboardService.java:29)
>   [classes/:na]

- second stack trace - not works ( web environment)

> 19:05:54.090 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] INFO
>   c.alvazan.orm.logging.NoSqlRawLogger - [rawlogger] starting NoSQL
>   Service Provider and connecting 19:05:54.101 [http-bio-8080-exec-3]
>   INFO c.a.o.l.s.d.c.ColumnFamilyHelper - On keyspace=dmpExisting column
>   families=[inputphasestru, stringindice, dbocolumnmeta, integerindice,
>   user, dbodatabasemeta, dbotablemeta] NOTE: WE WILL CREATE new column
>   families automatically as you save entites that have no column family
>   19:05:54.101 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] INFO
>   c.a.o.l.b.BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl - Begin scanning for jars with
>   nosql.Persistence.class 19:05:54.102 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] INFO
>   c.i.annovention.ClasspathDiscoverer - adding jar file for
>   scanning=jar:file:/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.30/wtpwebapps/teste28/WEB-INF/lib/playorm-1.4.3.jar!/
>   19:05:54.102 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] INFO
>   c.i.annovention.ClasspathDiscoverer - adding jar file for
>   scanning=jar:file:/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.30/lib/playorm-1.4.3.jar!/
>   19:05:54.102 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] INFO
>   c.i.annovention.ClasspathDiscoverer - adding jar file for
>   scanning=jar:file:/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.30/wtpwebapps/teste28/WEB-INF/lib/dmpDataAccess-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/ 19:05:54.119 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG
>   c.a.o.l.b.MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener -
>   class=com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.meta.DboColumnMeta
>   anno=com.alvazan.orm.api.base.anno.NoSqlEntity 19:05:54.119
>   [http-bio-8080-exec-3] INFO c.a.o.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass -
>   scanning class=class com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.meta.DboColumnMeta
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure scanning class(see chained
>   exception)=class com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.meta.DboColumnMeta at
>   com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.scanClass(MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.java:44)
>   at
>   com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.discovered(MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.java:34)
>   at
>   com.impetus.annovention.Discoverer.discoverAndIntimateForClassAnnotations(Discoverer.java:197)
>   at com.impetus.annovention.Discoverer.discover(Discoverer.java:155) at
>   com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl.rescan(BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:82)
>   at
>   com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl.setup(BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:133)
>   at
>   com.alvazan.orm.impl.bindings.BootstrapImpl.createInstanceImpl(BootstrapImpl.java:64)
>   at
>   com.alvazan.orm.impl.bindings.BootstrapImpl.createInstance(BootstrapImpl.java:35)
>   at com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:57) at
>   com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:52) at
>   com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:45) at
>   com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:24) at
>   com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.dao.PlayOrmConfiguration.init(PlayOrmConfiguration.java:45)
>   at
>   com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.dao.PlayOrmConfiguration.getEntityManager(PlayOrmConfiguration.java:51)
>   at
>   com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.dao.PlayOrmConfiguration.init(PlayOrmConfiguration.java:45)
>   at
>   com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.dao.PlayOrmConfiguration.getEntityManager(PlayOrmConfiguration.java:51)
>   at com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.dao.AbstractDao.getEm(AbstractDao.java:10) at
>   com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.dao.UserDao.findInputPhase(UserDao.java:201) at
>   com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.bean.InputPhaseStru.manageInputPhase(InputPhaseStru.java:105)
>   at
>   com.s1mbi0se.dashboard.service.DashboardService.readSolrLogFile(DashboardService.java:44)
>   at
>   com.s1mbi0se.dashboard.mbean.DashboardMBean.getTestehash(DashboardMBean.java:18)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at
>   javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:87) at
>   javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:67) at
>   org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:169)
>   at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183) at
>   org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
>   at
>   org.apache.jasper.el.JspValueExpression.getValue(JspValueExpression.java:106)
>   at
>   javax.faces.component._DeltaStateHelper.eval(_DeltaStateHelper.java:246)
>   at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:67) at
>   javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:150) at
>   org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.RendererUtils.getValue(RendererUtils.java:505)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.RendererUtils.getStringValue(RendererUtils.java:331)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.HtmlTextRendererBase.renderInputBegin(HtmlTextRendererBase.java:197)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.HtmlTextRendererBase.renderInput(HtmlTextRendererBase.java:186)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.HtmlTextRendererBase.encodeEnd(HtmlTextRendererBase.java:75)
>   at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:580)
>   at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:762)
>   at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:758)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.shared.view.JspViewDeclarationLanguageBase.actuallyRenderView(JspViewDeclarationLanguageBase.java:362)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.shared.view.JspViewDeclarationLanguageBase.renderView(JspViewDeclarationLanguageBase.java:199)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:285)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:115)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:241)
>   at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:199) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) Caused by:
>   com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:
>
> 1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could
>   not initialize class com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.meta.DboTableMeta at
>   com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.data.MetaClassInheritance.(MetaClassInheritance.java:25)
>   while locating com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.data.MetaClassInheritance
>
> 1 error at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:987)
>   at
>   com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.data.MetaInfo.findOrCreate(MetaInfo.java:58)
>   at
>   com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.addClass(ScannerForClass.java:59)
>   at
>   com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.scanClass(MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.java:42)
>   ... 63 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not
>   initialize class com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.meta.DboTableMeta at
>   com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.data.MetaAbstractClass.(MetaAbstractClass.java:17)
>   at
>   com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.data.MetaClassInheritance.(MetaClassInheritance.java:25)
>   at
>   com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.data.MetaClassInheritance$$FastClassByGuice$$9298a112.newInstance()
>   at
>   com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastConstructor.newInstance(FastConstructor.java:40)
>   at
>   com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:60)
>   at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
>   at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
>   at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:978)
>   at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1024)
>   at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:974)
>   ... 66 more

---

follows the whole stack trace ...

```
*** first stack trace - works fine locally (running outsite web)**

2013-02-13 19:20:18,173 com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass processIdFieldWorksWARN: We avoided double scanning a class=class com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.data.MetaClassSingle Everything will still work fine, but please send us the stack trace so we can see why this is happening
java.lang.RuntimeException: null
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.processIdFieldWorks(ScannerForClass.java:234) [playorm-1.4.3.jar:1.4.3 December 13 2012]
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.inspectFieldImpl(ScannerForClass.java:206) [playorm-1.4.3.jar:1.4.3 December 13 2012]
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.inspectField(ScannerForClass.java:193) [playorm-1.4.3.jar:1.4.3 December 13 2012]
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.scanFields(ScannerForClass.java:188) [playorm-1.4.3.jar:1.4.3 December 13 2012]
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.scanSingle(ScannerForClass.java:111) [playorm-1.4.3.jar:1.4.3 December 13 2012]
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.scanMultipleClasses(ScannerForClass.java:104) [playorm-1.4.3.jar:1.4.3 December 13 2012]
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.addClass(ScannerForClass.java:64) [playorm-1.4.3.jar:1.4.3 December 13 2012]
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.scanClass(MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.java:42) [playorm-1.4.3.jar:1.4.3 December 13 2012]
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.discovered(MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.java:34) [playorm-1.4.3.jar:1.4.3 December 13 2012]
    at com.impetus.annovention.Discoverer.discoverAndIntimateForClassAnnotations(Discoverer.java:197) [playorm-1.4.3.jar:1.4.3 December 13 2012]
    at com.impetus.annovention.Discoverer.discover(Discoverer.java:155) [playorm-1.4.3.jar:1.4.3 December 13 2012]
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl.rescan(BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:82) [playorm-1.4.3.jar:1.4.3 December 13 2012]
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl.setup(BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:133) [playorm-1.4.3.jar:1.4.3 December 13 2012]
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.bindings.BootstrapImpl.createInstanceImpl(BootstrapImpl.java:64) [playorm-1.4.3.jar:1.4.3 December 13 2012]
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.bindings.BootstrapImpl.createInstance(BootstrapImpl.java:35) [playorm-1.4.3.jar:1.4.3 December 13 2012]
    at com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:57) [playorm-1.4.3.jar:1.4.3 December 13 2012]
    at com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:52) [playorm-1.4.3.jar:1.4.3 December 13 2012]
    at com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:45) [playorm-1.4.3.jar:1.4.3 December 13 2012]
    at com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:24) [playorm-1.4.3.jar:1.4.3 December 13 2012]
    at com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.dao.PlayOrmConfiguration.init(PlayOrmConfiguration.java:45) [classes/:na]
    at com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.dao.PlayOrmConfiguration.getEntityManager(PlayOrmConfiguration.java:51) [classes/:na]
    at com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.dao.AbstractDao.getEm(AbstractDao.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.dao.UserDao.findInputPhase(UserDao.java:201) [classes/:na]
    at com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.bean.InputPhaseStru.manageInputPhase(InputPhaseStru.java:105) [classes/:na]
    at com.s1mbi0se.dashboard.service.DashboardService.readSolrLogFile(DashboardService.java:44) [classes/:na]
    at com.s1mbi0se.dashboard.service.DashboardService.main(DashboardService.java:29) [classes/:na]


*** second stack trace - not works ( web environment)**


19:05:54.090 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] INFO  c.alvazan.orm.logging.NoSqlRawLogger - [rawlogger] starting NoSQL Service Provider and connecting
19:05:54.101 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] INFO  c.a.o.l.s.d.c.ColumnFamilyHelper - On keyspace=dmpExisting column families=[inputphasestru, stringindice, dbocolumnmeta, integerindice, user, dbodatabasemeta, dbotablemeta]
NOTE: WE WILL CREATE new column families automatically as you save entites that have no column family
19:05:54.101 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] INFO  c.a.o.l.b.BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl - Begin scanning for jars with nosql.Persistence.class
19:05:54.102 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] INFO  c.i.annovention.ClasspathDiscoverer - adding jar file for scanning=jar:file:/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.30/wtpwebapps/teste28/WEB-INF/lib/playorm-1.4.3.jar!/
19:05:54.102 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] INFO  c.i.annovention.ClasspathDiscoverer - adding jar file for scanning=jar:file:/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.30/lib/playorm-1.4.3.jar!/
19:05:54.102 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] INFO  c.i.annovention.ClasspathDiscoverer - adding jar file for scanning=jar:file:/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.30/wtpwebapps/teste28/WEB-INF/lib/dmpDataAccess-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/
19:05:54.119 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG c.a.o.l.b.MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener - class=com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.meta.DboColumnMeta anno=com.alvazan.orm.api.base.anno.NoSqlEntity
19:05:54.119 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] INFO  c.a.o.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass - scanning class=class com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.meta.DboColumnMeta
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure scanning class(see chained exception)=class com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.meta.DboColumnMeta
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.scanClass(MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.java:44)
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.discovered(MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.java:34)
    at com.impetus.annovention.Discoverer.discoverAndIntimateForClassAnnotations(Discoverer.java:197)
    at com.impetus.annovention.Discoverer.discover(Discoverer.java:155)
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl.rescan(BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:82)
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl.setup(BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:133)
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.bindings.BootstrapImpl.createInstanceImpl(BootstrapImpl.java:64)
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.bindings.BootstrapImpl.createInstance(BootstrapImpl.java:35)
    at com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:57)
    at com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:52)
    at com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:45)
    at com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:24)
    at com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.dao.PlayOrmConfiguration.init(PlayOrmConfiguration.java:45)
    at com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.dao.PlayOrmConfiguration.getEntityManager(PlayOrmConfiguration.java:51)
    at com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.dao.PlayOrmConfiguration.init(PlayOrmConfiguration.java:45)
    at com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.dao.PlayOrmConfiguration.getEntityManager(PlayOrmConfiguration.java:51)
    at com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.dao.AbstractDao.getEm(AbstractDao.java:10)
    at com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.dao.UserDao.findInputPhase(UserDao.java:201)
    at com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.bean.InputPhaseStru.manageInputPhase(InputPhaseStru.java:105)
    at com.s1mbi0se.dashboard.service.DashboardService.readSolrLogFile(DashboardService.java:44)
    at com.s1mbi0se.dashboard.mbean.DashboardMBean.getTestehash(DashboardMBean.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:87)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:67)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:169)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
    at org.apache.jasper.el.JspValueExpression.getValue(JspValueExpression.java:106)
    at javax.faces.component._DeltaStateHelper.eval(_DeltaStateHelper.java:246)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:67)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:150)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.RendererUtils.getValue(RendererUtils.java:505)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.RendererUtils.getStringValue(RendererUtils.java:331)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.HtmlTextRendererBase.renderInputBegin(HtmlTextRendererBase.java:197)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.HtmlTextRendererBase.renderInput(HtmlTextRendererBase.java:186)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.HtmlTextRendererBase.encodeEnd(HtmlTextRendererBase.java:75)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:580)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:762)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:758)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared.view.JspViewDeclarationLanguageBase.actuallyRenderView(JspViewDeclarationLanguageBase.java:362)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared.view.JspViewDeclarationLanguageBase.renderView(JspViewDeclarationLanguageBase.java:199)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:285)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:115)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:241)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.meta.DboTableMeta
  at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.data.MetaClassInheritance.<init>(MetaClassInheritance.java:25)
  while locating com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.data.MetaClassInheritance

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:987)
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.data.MetaInfo.findOrCreate(MetaInfo.java:58)
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.addClass(ScannerForClass.java:59)
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.scanClass(MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.java:42)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.meta.DboTableMeta
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.data.MetaAbstractClass.<init>(MetaAbstractClass.java:17)
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.data.MetaClassInheritance.<init>(MetaClassInheritance.java:25)
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.data.MetaClassInheritance$$FastClassByGuice$$9298a112.newInstance(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastConstructor.newInstance(FastConstructor.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:978)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1024)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:974)
    ... 66 more
```

Thanks !

Andre

Comment: yes, this was added when dealing with classloading issues(it's a very complext issue and your jar was picked up twice most likely.  We need the FULL stack trace though to debug the issue).  thanks, Dean

Answer (score 1):

okay, there are really two separate issues going on

1. why are you getting the second scan
2. NoClassDefFoundError

Let's tackle the NoClassDefFoundError first.  Please don't get offended, but I am going to start from basic and work up as I don't know your level so you may already know this stuff.

1. We see a NoClassDefError or basically http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html
2. That we know can occur if a jar is missing, but in the code we see it called from another class that should be in the same jar anyways
3. Another time we get this error is we are in one newly created classloader by some framework
4. on this line here com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.dao.PlayOrmConfiguration.init(PlayOrmConfiguration.java:45) at  you should add a line like so

   Class temp = DboColumnMeta.class
   Class temp2 = MetaAbstractClass.class
   temp.getSimpleName();
   temp2.getSimpleName();

IF that class is not visible to your code, this is an issue of course that your code can't access it.  Does this pass or not?

Let's jump to issue #1 which is not a critical issue.  In the newest version, we have added a if(log.isDebugEnabled()) savePreviousTrace() so we can get both traces.  If you have time, you can check it out from git and run "./gradlew build" or "gradle.bat build" if you are on windows.

Let me know the status of number 2 as those line above "should" fail if it is failing down below in the code.

thanks,
Dean